# colorbox height and width is not set every second opening

Tags: jquery, colorbox

i have an issue with colorbox. 
the first launch it's ok, the second launch is has width of 0 and height of 20, 
third launch it's ok again (700/700px), then fourth 0/20 etc

the code is really simple for the opening:

```
    $(".invoicepullhours").colorbox({
        iframe:true, 
        width:'700px', 
        height:'700px'               
     });
```

i use jquery 1.7.1 and the target comes from the href. changing the href link has no effect. a screenshot on dropbox from the inspector: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6939592/stackoverflow-colorbox.png
the console doesn't show any errors.

anyone?

cheers,
dave.

Comment: Looks like invalid html markup (from your screenshot). Body tag has extra `"`, after iframe we have `" "`. Are you sure that html is valid?

Comment: you're right, removed the extra quote. but however it's not the cause of this issue, problem persists. i also have it when i load a random external url in the iframe...

Comment: Sounds like you've left out of your post whatever it is that you are doing that is the real cause of the problem.  You should post a demo because right now you are just asking folks to take a stab in the dark.

Comment: you're right Jack, but lots of js floating around in the site and was too complex to make a small jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually solved it by updating to v1.4.10 from v1.4.8...

Answer (score 0):

do not add additional classes to your "a" tag. the "class='iframe'" is sufficient; then after the "ColorBox" itself decides how to open it in any browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'/>
        <title>Colorbox Examples</title>
        <style>
            body{font:12px/1.2 Verdana, sans-serif; padding:0 10px;}
            a:link, a:visited{text-decoration:none; color:#416CE5; border-bottom:1px solid #416CE5;}
            h2{font-size:13px; margin:15px 0 0 0;}
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../jquery.colorbox.last.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".iframe").colorbox({
        iframe: true,
        width: "700px",
        height: "700px"
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<p><a class='iframe' href="http://wikipedia.com">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```